# IE / Edge CSS3 Transitions not working with background-position property

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions, microsoft-edge

I know I'm talking about IE but I *think* `transition` property was fixed in more recent (Edge?) versions.

I'm trying to transition the `background-position` of an element (see demo below) but for whatever reason it's not working in IE...  :'-(

In the demo below, the "Click Me" button should be highlighting the adjacent text but not so for IE.

If you toggle the "Toggle Display" button, you'll see the background color shows up (after the transition of course) because toggling `display:none`  is forcing the repaint.  I know `background-size` may not be `transition`-able in IE but does that affect my single transition property on the `background-position`? Any way to have this background color transition from left to right (see demo in any other browser than IE for desired effect)?

Thanks!

```js
/** JS only to facilitate the test and trigger the CSS on button click **/
var myHighlighter = document.querySelector('.button');
var myToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');

myHighlighter.addEventListener('click', press)
// toggling `display:none` just forces a repaint
myToggle.addEventListener('click', toggle);

function press(e) {
  var newState = (e.target.getAttribute('aria-pressed')!=="true");
  e.target.setAttribute('aria-pressed', newState);
}

function toggle(e) {
  var isToggled = (e.target.previousElementSibling.getAttribute('style'))
  if (isToggled) {
    e.target.previousElementSibling.removeAttribute('style');
  } else {
    e.target.previousElementSibling.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
  }
}
```

```css
/* conditional CSS for transition based on presence of `aria-pressed="true"` attribute */
.button + .text {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, orange 50%, transparent 50%) no-repeat;
  background-position:right bottom;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  transition: none;
}

.button[aria-pressed="true"] + .text {
  background-position: left bottom;
  transition: background-position .5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button"
        class="button"
        aria-pressed="false"> 
        Click Me
  </button>

  <span class="text">IE won't transition the background-position (color highlighting) initially without toggleing the display (repaint)</span>
  <button class="toggle">Toggle Display</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of IE? Transitions do not work in IE<10 at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the transition property to the first set, so it looks like this:

```
.button + .text {
background: linear-gradient(to right, orange 50%, transparent 50%) no-repeat;
background-position:right bottom;
background-size: 200% 100%;
transition: background-position .5s linear;
}

.button[aria-pressed="true"] + .text {
background-position: left bottom;
}
```

Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to add your snippet to my existing answer...

Add to your CSS:

```
.text {
display:block;
}
```

This made it work in IE. Here is your edited code:
https://jsfiddle.net/kellyking/2zLhz8t6/2/

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to fix it for me, can you copy my snippet to your answer and update? Also, I didn't want the transition when going back to the original state, that's why I have `transition:none` on the first css block.

Comment: What do you mean by "IE Edge"? There is no such thing.

Comment: I mean, what the poster asked about "I know I'm talking about IE but I think transition property was fixed in more recent (Edge?) versions."

Comment: Thanks @Kelly, the `display:block` does fix it :-) The other part about moving the transition wasn't required (maybe remove that part?)

Comment: @Kelly, I just updated your answer and removed the first part as it wasn't necessary. Simply put, `inline` elements aren't transition-able in IE and so display block on my `span` was required. Thanks again!